# Component cannot find symbol error Java

Tags: java, jtable, components, renderer

```
public class cellRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable tblPackage, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasocus, int row, int col)
    {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(tblPackage, value, isSelected, hasocus, row, col);
        if(tblPackage.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).getIdentifier().equals("Package Status"))
        {
            if(value.toString().equals("ACTIVE"))
            {
                c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

The symbol shows that it cannot find the symbol...what's the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about a compile time error but I don't have one. This class
compiles fine (and I didn't make any changes to your code except adding import
statements). So check if you have all import statements correct.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class cellRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable tblPackage, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasocus, int row, int col)
    {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(tblPackage, value, isSelected, hasocus, row, col);
        if(tblPackage.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).getIdentifier().equals("Package Status"))
        {
            if(value.toString().equals("ACTIVE"))
            {
                c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your return statement it should be the component so use the below:

```
 return c;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
return this;
```

this statement is **wrong**. Because `this` refers to the current object and you need to return the component.

So you need to replace `this` by `c` like

```
return c;
```

**EDIT:**

Try this I am not sure about this but...

```
tblPackage.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableCellRenderer(){
    private DefaultTableCellRenderer DEFAULT_RENDERER =  new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable tblPackage, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
                Component c = DEFAULT_RENDERER.getTableCellRendererComponent(tblPackage, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
        if(tblPackage.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).getIdentifier().equals("Package Status"))
        {
            if(value.toString().equals("ACTIVE"))
            {
                c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }

                return c;
            }

        });
```